# How to change models via ajax request with default Phalcon Application

Tags: php, ajax, phalcon

I have a grid that is showing all user of my application using the Phalcon models.

```
$users = User::find();
//call my method to display the Grid.
```

Each rows of my grid have action buttons that can edit/delete an entity.

[image: action_buttons]

I would like to update my grid via ajax call with jQuery but I don't know how to structure my application with the "ajax" part since all `Actions` are in `Controllers` that automaticly generate `Routes`

Should I create a Phalcon `Micro Application` to manage my calls ?

Should I create custom routes in a `Phalcon\Mvc\Router` in my main application that will update my models ?

Is it possible to create `Controller's Actions` that phalcon won't automaticly manage and to bind them on a "different url" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know id i understood your question correctly. For ajax just creat a custom Action in the controller like

```
 ajaxAction{
    $this->view->disable();
    ///anything else you want to return to ajax
   }
```

and in you $.ajax request give path to the action eg: user/ajax

Comment: This is exacly what I wanted. Thank you